# Dynamic Table Rows with docx-template

Tags: python, python-docx

Good day SO,

I am trying to dynamically populate a Table in a .docx file. The table looks like:
[image]
Where there are N projects (1..N) and each project has N rows (1..N), making the structure like such:

```
table_data = [
{
    'title':'Proj1',
    'rows':[
        {'col1':'col1txt',
        'col2':'col2txt',
        'col3':'col3txt',
        'col4':'col4txt',
        'col5':'col5txt',
        'col6':'col6txt'},
        {'col1':'col1txt',
        'col2':'col2txt',
        'col3':'col3txt',
        'col4':'col4txt',
        'col5':'col5txt',
        'col6':'col6txt'}
        ]
    },
    {..repeat..}
]

context={'table_data':table_data}
```

I am currently using the python-docx-template library, and there are very few example online regarding nested tables. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SOLUTION:

I found the information required for this nested table case at:
https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/subdoc_tpl.docxhttps://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/subdoc_tpl.docx

and it's syntax at:
https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/dynamic_table.py

Hope this helps somebody like me :) Good day!

[image]

Comment: This table looks like it can be handled with merged cells for the project title, so should not require nesting tables.

Comment: Is there a guide or example I could follow for this? Sorry im new with the jinja templating scheme, so I do not know how to make such rows repeatable N times..

Comment: Thank you! This helps loads to understand how tables work with docxtpl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the information required for this nested table case at: https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/subdoc_tpl.docxhttps://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/subdoc_tpl.docx

and it's syntax at: https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/dynamic_table.py

Comment: Hi Benji, the 1st link does not exist anymore. Can you send me some other link or the code to do it?

Comment: @RaghavChamadiya the link is posted two times, that's the problem. You need to cut between `.docx` and `https`. Otherwise the link works fine still